Read Paradox database in .net 64 bits
Is there a way to read Paradox database files in .net 64 bits?
I've recently uploaded an app to 64 bits from 32 bits.
The Paradox files were being read with an OleDBConnection with the following connection string:
connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=Paradox 4.x;Data Source=" + pathToDBFile + ";";
Now i'm in 64 bits i also changed the MS Access database engine to 2016(64 bits).
I've tried with ODBC without success, also tried Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.
I'm now reading about 'Borland Database Engine' paired with 'Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010' as a possible hack to do this. Has anyone managed to read this type of files from a .net 64 bits app ? Thanks

A general workaround for issues like this is to run your existing 32bit code "out of process" and use some form of IPC to communicate.

Is there a reason to change the app from 32 to 64 bit? for example another dependency that's only 64 bit?
